# Get entire column text of a table using Watir

Tags: ruby, element, watir

I know that using the following code we can get the entire row text in WATIR

```
# row 2 - entire text
table1 = browser.table(:id => "table")
puts table1[1].text
```

How can we get the entire column text like this?

Comment: You have to collect all rows, and then iterate through it. This is a basic way of doing.

Comment: No easier way? like any ready api in watir?

Comment: I am not sure.. Iterating is not so *complex* I believe.. :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are some built-in methods to help get column data, however it is different between Watir-Webdriver and Watir-Classic.

Let us assume that we are working with the table:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1a</td>
    <td>1b</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2a</td>
    <td>2b</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Solution - Watir-Webdriver and Watir-Classic**

The Table class has a `strings` method that returns the text of the table as a 2D array. The array is of rows, but you can use `transpose` to get it to be columns.

```
columns = browser.table(:id => "table").strings.transpose
p columns[0]
#=> ["1a", "2a"]
p columns[1]
#=> ["1b", "2b"]
```

**Solution - Watir-Classic**

In Watir-Classic, the Table class also has a built-in `column_values` method, which means you can simply do:

```
p browser.table(:id => "table").column_values(0)
#=> ["1a", "2a"]
p browser.table(:id => "table").column_values(1)
#=> ["1b", "2b"]
```

**Solution - Iteration**

You can of course also iterate through each row and collect the cell in each column:

```
p browser.table(:id => "table").trs.collect{ |tr| tr[0].text }
#=> ["1a", "2a"]
p browser.table(:id => "table").trs.collect{ |tr| tr[1].text }
#=> ["1b", "2b"]
```

Comment: That's why you are my favorite *watirist*..:-)

Comment: Wonderful!! I had tries the column values with the classic but didnt know about transpose in watir-webdriver. Thank u :)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if there's any ready API. So here's the workaround :

```
table1 = browser.table(:id => "table")
row_count = table1.rows.length
for k in 0..row_count-1
  puts table1[k][1].text
end
```

Comment: Ohh! GOD. You are still *kid* in Ruby. :-) We don't use `for`, we use `#each`. :-) Don't worry there is a way, look at the above answer, @Justin, who has all the watir *solutions* in this pocket.

Comment: we have to use '#each' on the table rows so that we iterate through every row for that particular column right? 'table1.rows' cant provide a fixnum for the loop. Help me here?

Comment: Didn't Justin's answer helped you ?

Comment: Yes it did. Very much :) Just wanna try this too.